# 'public static void' can't be called from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have a static method in `Player.cs` that I can't call. It should let me use it and refresh the player when called via `GameManager.cs`

I've tried changing the name of the reference to itself however that just spews out more errors.

**GameManager.CS**

```cs
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        public Player PlayerPrefab;

        [HideInInspector]
        public Player LocalPlayer;

        private void Awake()
        {
            if (!PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            player.RefreshInstance(ref LocalPlayer, PlayerPrefab);
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

        }

        public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Photon.Realtime.Player newPlayer)
        {
            base.OnPlayerEnteredRoom(newPlayer);
            player.RefreshInstance(ref LocalPlayer, PlayerPrefab);
        }
    }
```

**Player.cs**

```cs
    public class Player : MonoBehaviourPun
    {
            public static void RefreshInstance(ref Player player, Player Prefab)
        {
            var position = Vector3.zero;
            var rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            if (player != null)
            {
                position = player.transform.position;
                rotation = player.transform.rotation;
                PhotonNetwork.Destroy(player.gameObject);
            }

            player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Prefab.gameObject.name, position, rotation).GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> `` CS0117: `Photon.Realtime.Player' does not contain a definition for
>   `RefreshInstance' ``

Sorry if this lacks quality, it's my first post.

Comment: try Player.RefreshInstance(ref LocalPlayer, PlayerPrefab); - uppercase "P" - static method should be referenced by type, not instance

Comment: You can't call static methods on an instance because they are not part of that instance.

Comment: You would need to call it as Player.RefreshInstance(....) as it is a static on the class.. as ColinM said, not the instance.

Comment: @PiotrWojsa I think your answer worked! Thanks for that.